# Convert string to calculable operation

Tags: python, string, math

Is it possible to convert string to a calculable operation

I want to make this done:

```
>>> import math
>>> operation = "10/2*6 + math.sqrt(42)"
>>> compute(operation)
36.48074069840786
```

Comment: Sure, that's what the builtin `eval` does ... But doing this can lead to security issues.

Comment: Don't [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: what about `literaleval`, its a bit safer.

Comment: @InbarRose `literal_eval()` doesn't works for mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` will do that for you.

```
>>> import math
>>> operation = "10/2*6 + math.sqrt(42)"
>>> eval(operation)
36.48074069840786
```

Comment: `eval(operation.replace('__',''),{'__builtins__':None,'math':math})` may be a bit safer ...