# How to turn a string into an operation?

Tags: python

How can I turn this string:

```
a = "1 + 2 + 3"
```

into an operation which will output `6`? Is there any code made for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to calculable operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939308/convert-string-to-calculable-operation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> a = "1 + 2 + 3"
>>> eval(a)
6
```